# std::vector of std::tuples leads to unknown size

Tags: c++11, vector, visual-studio-2013, tuples

I want to store three arbitrary ints inside a std::vector without defining a struct/class. So I went for std::tuple<>:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int>
```

Using MS VS 2013, it leads to the following error:

```
>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector(1628): error C2036: 'std::tuple<unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int> *' : unknown size
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector(1622) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Tidy(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::tuple<unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector(945) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Tidy(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::tuple<unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int>
1>          ]
1>          d:\projects\gl33\src\nvf.cpp(39) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::tuple<unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int>
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =======
```

Is this due to limitations in the MSVS2013 compiler? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I guess you forgot to include the `<tuple>` header: `#include <tuple>` - I can reproduce your error message when only including `<vector>` but not `<tuple>`.

Comment: Damn it, you're right. Just thought that it had already been included. Thanks for the comment. Would you repost as an answer that I can mark as solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A class type is known (its name is known) but its size is unknown if the type has only been forward-declared, but not defined. E.g.

```
struct X;

sizeof(X) // error: X is incomplete
```

The size of a type is important for pointer arithmetic, which is another hint when looking at the compiler error (which mentions a pointer to `tuple`).

MSDN provides the [following example for C2036](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kay26wa.aspx):

```
struct A* pA;
int main() {
   pA++;   // C2036, size of A not known
   ((char*&)pA)++;   // OK, if sizeof(A) == sizeof(char)
}
```

Where the `struct A* pa` implicitly forward-declares `struct A`.

---

Such a situation can happen with headers of the Standard Library when you don't include all required headers yourself. There are interdependencies between the types in the Standard Library. If a Standard Library header requires only a forward-declaration of `tuple`, it won't include the heavyweight `tuple` header itself in an effort to reduce compilation times.

I could reproduce the issue in the OP by including only `<vector>` but not `<tuple>`. Solution: manually include all headers you need types from - when using `vector<tuple<..>>`, include `<tuple>` (as well as `<vector>`). In general, including a header guarantees the availability of a certain set of types. To maximize portability, always make sure the headers you've included guarantee that you can use all the types in your program<sup>(*)</sup>.

<sup>(*)</sup> More specifically, you should make sure that you have a definition for all types your program needs a definition for. Standard Library containers require their value types to be complete (at least at the point where the class template is instantiated). Hence, if your program requires a definition of `vector<tuple<unsigned, unsigned>>`, it also requires a definition of `tuple<unsigned, unsigned>`.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration on the topic!